# How to send a request with data using System.Net.HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, url-encoding

I want to send simple GET request using System.Net.WebRequest. But i have a problem when I try to send on URL-s that contains "Space" character.
What i do:

```
string url = "https://example.com/search?text=some words&page=8";
var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(link) as HttpWebRequest;
```

If i try to use this code, then 
`webRequest.Address == "https://example.com/search?&text=some words&page=8"`   (#1)

I can manually add "%20" for UrlEncoded space, but "WebRequest.Create" decodes it, and again i have (#1).  How can i do it right?

P.S. sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a plus sign (+) instead of space. Also drop the first ampersand (&); it is only used on non-primary arguments. As in

```
var url = "https://example.com/search?text=some+words&page=8";
```

Comment: It's not working. Result:webRequest.Address ==  "http://exmple.com/index.php?some+words"

Answer (score 1):

You should make parameter values "url-friendly". To achieve that, you must "url-encode" values, using HttpUtility.UrlEncode(). This fixes not only spaces, but many other dangerous "quirks":

```
string val1 = "some words"; 
string val2 = "a <very bad> value & with specials!";
string url = "https://example.com/search?text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(val1) + "&comment=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(val2);
```

Comment: Yes, its(HttpUtility.UrlEncode()) encodes spaces and others, but than "WebRequest.Create(link)" decodes %20 to spaces =) I don't understand its logic...

Comment: Don't be confused, it's quite simple, if you know the difference between "internet URL" and "page parameters": internet URLs (consider them like the "full path of the executable" you need to run) don't like spaces, to be replaced by %20 (hex value of blank, %20=32) with the so-called "HttpEncode", while parameters (essentially like program "command line parameters") need to be correctly encoded with "UrlEncode" to map spaces (to "+" sign) and any other "non-standard" characters. That's why you need two types of encoding. If you are clear, I hope you consider my answer as "correct"..:-)